# If section has class active then add it's id to body as a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sections

I would be grateful if you help with this thing, I can't resolve. I am trying to create a function:
"if any section has class "active" => take this section's id then 
 add it to body as a class element otherwise remove"

This the code below, but it's not working properly or when I scroll to next section new class is not being added and previous one removed.

```
<body class="">
    <section id="home" class="active">
    </section>

    <section id="about" class="">
    </section>
</body>

if ($('section').hasClass('active')) {
    var dataSection = $('section').attr('id');
    $body.addClass(dataSection.replace('#', '') + '-active');   
} else {
    $body.removeClass('home-active');
}
```

Comment: `.replace()` call is not necesary, `.id` property does not include `"#"` character

Comment: `$body.addClass($(this).attr('class'))` instead of `$body.addClass(dataSection.replace('#', '') + '-active');`

Comment: Do you have your `$body` variable defined somewhere or did you intend to use `$('body')`?

Comment: When is `if..else`  used? `$('section').hasClass('active')` would only query and return `Boolean` result of first `<section>` element

Comment: @ViliamAboši yes i have $body defined in js file

Comment: @guest271314 hmm, complicated a bit :(

Comment: @HAJIHASHIMOV Can you include full `html`, `javascript` at Question, create stacksnippets to demonstrate? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Lixus but i want to add the class itsself  +  -active to the body, for example home-active !?

Answer (score 2):

Try using `this` here.

```
if( $(something).hasClass("active") ){
    var grabId = $(this).attr("id");
    $("body").attr("id", grabId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked as well:), but my question was that when second section is active that id + active is not added to Body. still trying to test different variants but won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$('section').attr('id')` that will always return the `id` of the first section, You need to use `this` inside of `section` in :

```
$('section').attr('id');
```

Should be :

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

So it will get the id of the current section, Also no need for the replace the both lines could be combined to :

```
$body.addClass($(this).attr('id') + '-active');
```

**NOTE :** You could always get the active section using just selector like :

```
$('section.active')
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it kind of worked but it says undefined-active and when scroll to for example about section => the about-active is being added to body? maybe its because of $this or ?

Comment: Yes, my bad `$('this')` should be `$(this)` (post updated).

Comment: Thank you it worked :), but my question was that when second section is active that id + active is not added to Body. still trying to test different variants but won't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Actually `$('section').attr('id')` will give you the id attribute without `#` you can use it directly, you can see body `class` changed accordingly in the folowing Demo:

```js
if ($('section').hasClass('active')) {
  $("body").addClass($('section').attr('id') + '-active');
} else {
  $("body").removeClass('home-active');
}

console.log($("body").attr('class'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body class="">
  <section id="home" class="active">
  </section>

  <section id="about" class="">
  </section>
</body>
```

**Note:**

Note that you are using `$body` which you haven't declared, use `$("body")` instead to refer document body.

Comment: Thank you it worked :), but can't add another class to body after second section got active.

Comment: @HajiHashimov The actual code is only triggering on document load, you have to recall it whenever you change any section.